# Running a script on leaving an i3 workspace

Tags: keyboard-layout, i3, workspaces, window-switching

Does i3 have the ability to run a script whenever one leaves
a workspace?  I ask because I would like a certain keyboard
layout in emacs (including hyper) and a different one outside of emacs
(including mode switch). I have a small keyboard.

Comment: I don't think so, but if you only switch workspaces via keyboard shortcuts, you could remap those to a script that switches the workspace *and* changes the keyboard layout.

Answer (score 0):

I3 doesn't appear to have this feature, but you can do this independently from the window manager. [Kbdd](https://github.com/qnikst/kbdd) can switch the keyboard layout on a window switch, and works with most window managers including i3. You do need to be running D-Bus.

A remaining difficulty is that kbdd remembers settings per window but has no built-in ability to select the layout for a window when that window is created. I think you can use [`for_window`](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#for_window) to run [`exec`](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#exec) when a window is created and call `dbus-send` to let kbdd know which layout to use. [This email thread](https://www.mail-archive.com/i3-discuss@i3.zekjur.net/msg01970.html) suggests hooking directly on the [IPC](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#_interprocess_communication); I don't know how you'd do that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no ready-to-use feature built into *i3* to do that. But you can use the *i3 IPC interface* to watch for [workspace events](http://i3wm.org/docs/ipc.html#_workspace_event) and then run the appropriate command.

There is a (probably incomplete) [list of libraries](http://i3wm.org/docs/ipc.html#_see_also_existing_libraries) for a number of different programming languages at the end of the documentation.